# Accessing IOptions<T> object .NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am new to .NET Core and so apologies if this is a newbie question. 
I created a Web API project in .NET Core 2 using VS 2017.

For me, I have `appsettings.json` file with some connection settings.

After reading about `IOptions<T>` from microsoft tutorials, i am doing something like the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);

    // I want to access MyOptions object here to configure other services?how do i do that?

    service.AddHangfire( // Get MyOptions.HangfireConenctionString etc.)
}
```

How do I access the created `MYOptions` object in `ConfigureServices` and also if I need to access it in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,..)` method?

I only saw examples of injection `IOptions<T>` in controllers in the tutorials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do we need IOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844022/when-do-we-need-ioptions)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use some settings in

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Load the settings directly at startup.
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection("Root:MySettings").Get<MySettings>();

    // Verify mailSettings here (if required)

    service.AddHangfire(
        // use settings variable here
    );

    // If the settings needs to be injected, do this:
    container.AddSingleton(settings);
}
```

In case you require your configuration object to be used inside an application component **do not** inject an `IOptions<T>` into your component, because that only causes unforatunate downsides, as explained [here](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/servicecollectionintegration.html#working-with-ioptions). Instead, inject the value directly, as shown in the following example.

```
public class HomeController : Controller  
{
    private MySettings _settings;
    public HomeController(MySettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Steven

Comment: comparing Steven's and @Frank Nielsen answers, which startup method is recommended? and why?

Comment: Please don't present opinions on why `IOptions<T>` is the wrong answer as the gospel truth. There are few absolutes in programming.

Answer (score 6):

You are close

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Bind(options));
```

You can now access your MyOptions using dependency injection

```
public class HomeController : Controller  
{
    private MySettings _settings;
    public HomeController(IOptions<MySettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value
        // _settings.StringSetting == "My Value";
    }
}
```

I took the snippets from this excellent article: https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/ by Andrew Lock.

Comment: I can't comment @Steven post due to reputation, but he is one right track about the injection. Thanks for notice.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your `appsettings.json` and how you *name* the section. For example:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "MySettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "post.gres:39484"
  }
}
```

Here, the *name* of the section is *MySettings*. Normally, in ASP.NET Core 2.2 in my `Startup.cs`, I use something like:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

But something like this also works:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.AddOptions<MyOptions>().Bind(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

If you have configured your program to use `AddEnvironmentVariables()`, then the settings can also be set by adding a config variable named `MySettings__ConnectionString`. [The value can come from multiple places](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#providers).

If you want to [validate your options class you might want to use Data Annotations](https://keestalkstech.com/2019/09/validate-strongly-typed-options-when-using-config-sections/).